# Query with multiple Left Joins to ODBC tables fails

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2013

I posted this originally without all the ODBC information.  After further investigation the problem appears to the ODBC related.  Given the change, I wanted to report and see if an ODBC guru might be "listening".

I have the following queries in Access...

Query #1

```
SELECT aa.DocNum, b.QualityClass
FROM dbo_TransferHistory AS aa LEFT JOIN PCQualityClass AS bb ON aa.DocNum = bb.DocumentNum
WHERE (((aa.DocNum)=[Enter Doc Num]));
```

Which I want to expand to...
Query #2

```
SELECT aa.DocNum, bb.QualityClass, cc.BldgCond
FROM (dbo_TransferHistory AS aa LEFT JOIN PCQualityClass AS bb ON aa.DocNum = bb.DocumentNum) 
      LEFT JOIN PCBldgCond AS cc ON aa.DocNum = cc.DocumentNum
WHERE (((aa.DocNum)=[Enter Doc Num]));
```

dbo_TransferHistory is an table I access through an ODBC connector.
PCQualityClass and PCBldgCond are two queries that are based off another ODBC table.  The SQL for those queries is ...

Query for PCQualityClass

```
SELECT aa.DocumentNum, aa.Value AS QualityClass, aa.ResourceID, aa.BldgSeqNum
FROM dbo_PCBldgDetail AS aa
WHERE (((aa.DocumentNum)=[Enter Doc Num]) AND ((aa.ResourceID)="QualityClass") AND ((aa.BldgSeqNum)=[Enter Bldg Num]));
```

Query for PCBldgCond

```
SELECT aa.DocumentNum, aa.Value AS BldgCond, aa.BldgSeqNum, aa.ResourceID
FROM dbo_PCBldgDetail
WHERE (((aa.DocumentNum)=[Enter Doc Num]) AND ((aa.BldgSeqNum)=[Enter BldgNum]) AND ((aa.ResourceID)="Condition"));
```

DocNum and DocumentNum are the same type ("Short Text" and a length of 12) and while I would like to make the names the same, I cannot.
When the query is run, an Inputbox pops up and [Enter Doc Num] is replaced with the Document Number I want the data for.

The queries were created in Access using the Create Query tool.  Access is willing to create the query and the SQL looks good.

The problem is that while Query #1 will work, Query #2 causes the error "Invalid Operation".  As a note, if I take the first join out of query #2 and run the remainder as a single join, the query works.

Changing to inner joins will allow Query #2 to function but will cause issues as there are times that one or both of the two sub queries do not have data but I still need the data from the primary table.

Changing from ODBC tables to local tables solves the problem but is not a viable solution as the ODBC tables cannot be local.

Does anyone have any insight into the inter-workings of Access and ODBC?  I have a hard time believing that I am the first person who has tried to build an Access/Odbc query with more than one join.  Yet I have not been able to Google a solution to this problem.

Comment: Very interesting issue.Never heard or experienced it. Is that the entire error: *Invalid Operation*?  What happens if you try *Query 1* with `LEFT JOIN PCBldgCond...` table as this may be the problem? Also, post the SQL of these subqueries.

Comment: #1: Yes, that is the entire text of the error.

#2: Using the join for PcBlgCond by itself in Query #1 works.  The error only hits when there are multiple left joins and only using ODBC source tables.  Inner joins work but there will be instances where one of the joined queries has zero records.  Similarly, the multiple join query works on local tables but that is not a possible solution.  

Lastly, I edited the original post to show the SQL for the two subqueries.

Comment: Just to make sure it's not doing something strange with order of operations, none of those brackets seem necessary.  Not sure if `FROM (dbo_TransferHistory AS aa LEFT JOIN PCQualityClass AS bb ON aa.DocNum = bb.DocumentNum) 
      LEFT JOIN PCBldgCond AS cc ON aa.DocNum = cc.DocumentNum` will evaluate differently from `FROM dbo_TransferHistory AS aa LEFT JOIN PCQualityClass AS bb ON aa.DocNum = bb.DocumentNum
      LEFT JOIN PCBldgCond AS cc ON aa.DocNum = cc.DocumentNum`

Comment: The parentheses are an Access thing.  If I do not include them, Access will not even save the query.  It is like the parentheses around "...WHERE (((aa.DocumentNum)=[Enter Doc Num]) AND...".  Totally unneeded but added by Access.

Comment: Try changing the `aa` aliases in subqueries as it may clash with outer query.

Comment: @Parfait - Nice idea but already thought of that.  Set the aliases in all three queries to unique names and it still reports "Invalid Operator".

Comment: Try hardcoding input parameters: *DocNum* and *BldgSeqNum* in all queries. Also, `Value` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) so wrap it in brackets or backticks. Also, you should use forms and parameterized queries for such inputs.

Comment: What's your backend? Can some of these queries be moved to passthrough queries?

Comment: Left-joins on ODBC DAO seem to cause problems in general.
Maybe try doing it as a pass-through query, so you can use SQL Server syntax. Your sub queries can be done as  SQL temp tables. Make sure you set NOCOUNT on so SQL Server doesn't show the records affected messages.

Comment: Your edits indicate no table alias in the Query for PCBldgCond - perhaps @Parfait is on the right track with both suggestions? If you have updated SQL - it should be posted as an edit/update to your question.